# Pandas - Flatten multi-index table without drop the index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

With an original csv file, I make a new pivot table:

```
version_pivot_table = treatcriteria_data.pivot_table(index=['version'], columns=['week'], values=['hours'], aggfunc='sum')
```

I obtain this table:

```
                              hours                               
week                             47             48             49   
version                                                
147.0.0.35            119404.056481  103956.232244            NaN   
147.1.0.4                       NaN   52494.531709  145452.572156   
148.0.0.16                      NaN            NaN            NaN
```

I want to have this table, a flatten table but without dropping the 'version' column, and with a 'Total' row:

```
version                   47               48               49
147.0.0.35     119404.056481    103956.232244              NaN   
147.1.0.4                NaN     52494.531709    145452.572156 
148.0.0.16               NaN              NaN              NaN 
Total          119404.056481    156450.763954    145452.572156
```

Edit: Thanks for your answers, but I forgot to specify that the indexes of the columns are integers, which respectively gives me these error messages:

> ValueError: expected a value of type str, got 47 of type int

> ValueError: expected a value of type str, got ('hours', 47) of type tuple

Comment: Hi could you post some of the original data? to quickly try it before posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to precise '47', '48', '49' are of integer type, I had this error message:

> ValueError: expected a value of type str, got ('hours', '47') of type tuple

I solved this with this code:

```
version_pivot_table.columns = version_pivot_table.columns.get_level_values(1)
version_pivot_table = version_pivot_table.reset_index()
version_pivot_table= version_pivot_table.append(version_pivot_table.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
version_pivot_table.at[len(version_pivot_table.index) - 1, 'version'] = 'Total'
```

The result:

```
           version      47       48      49
147.0.0.35_E0_V298  119404   103956                   
 147.1.0.4_E0_V299          52494.5  145453 
148.0.0.16_E0_V300                                    
             Total  119404   156451  145453
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
>>> version_pivot_table.droplevel(level=0, axis=1).rename_axis(index=None, columns='version')

version                47             48             49
147.0.0.35  119404.056481  103956.232244            NaN
147.1.0.4             NaN   52494.531709  145452.572156
148.0.0.16            NaN            NaN            NaN
```

For the `Total` row, I recommend you to use `margins=True` and `margins_name='Total'` as argument of `pivot_table` then drop the column `Total`. Something like this:

```
version_pivot_table = \
    treatcriteria_data.pivot_table(index='version', columns='week',
                                   values='hours', aggfunc='sum',
                                   margins=True, margins_name='Total') \
                      .drop(columns='Total').droplevel(level=0, axis=1) \
                      .rename_axis(index=None, columns='version')
```

Comment: I had a problem with your solution because '47', '48', '49' are of integer type, but I succeeded after this code:
version_pivot_table.columns = version_pivot_table.columns.get_level_values(1)
    version_pivot_table = version_pivot_table.reset_index()
    version_pivot_table= version_pivot_table.append(version_pivot_table.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
    version_pivot_table.at[len(version_pivot_table.index) - 1, 'version'] = 'Total'